# Anyone else having third-party modules with data integrity issues in M2's checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, third-party-module, calendar

Using Amasty for a shipping calendar and orders randomly (It seems?) come through to the admin with shipping date missing. Very annoying but there is no obvious pattern and the bug can't be replicated by Amasty, although they were able to see it happen once in testing. I heard from a couple of devs that they have heard other people having issues with data integrity using third-party extensions with Magento 2's checkout. Has anyone seen anything like this? Thoughts?

Comment: using version 2.2.8 currently